# Im trying to add an extra CSS file to my wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wpml

Im trying to add an extra CSS file to my wordpress theme and switch between them as i switch website languages.

I added this code to my header.php file

```
<?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "ar"): ?><link rel="stylesheet" href="myfile.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

and it doesnt seem to work, do i need to add another piece of code in another file to work?
Im using wpml plugin

Comment: Can you echo out `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` to see it's value?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in the functions.php file of your theme.

**path_to_your_theme/functions.php :**

This method is the right method to add some CSS files to your theme :

```
function custom_scripts() {
 if(get_bloginfo( 'language' ) == "en-US"){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'us_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style-us.css' );
 }
 elseif(get_bloginfo( 'language' ) == "fr-FR"){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fr_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style-fr.css' );
 }
 ...
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
```

I use wp_enqueue_style(), it's a safe way to add/enqueue a CSS style file to the wordpress generated page.

Codex page : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style